# DB record save time very high in hibernate ! Why is it?

Tags: database, hibernate, unit-testing

I am recording the save time for 10000 records and I don't know why on earth is it taking 40 mins approx to save 10000 records. I have a class where all the basic session factory work is done and then I extend(inherit that into the [DAO(nameofentity)] class name and ask for a getsession and then the save function. Why on earth is it taking so much time? I have log4j initializer it scrolls down like a big display.

Here is the code of the baseclass for obtaining a session in hibernate.

```
package DAO;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class BaseDAO {
private static final ThreadLocal<Session> session= new ThreadLocal<Session>();

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
        .configure().buildSessionFactory();

public  Session getSession() {

    Session session = (Session) BaseDAO.session.get();
    if (session == null) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        BaseDAO.session.set(session);
    }
    return session;
}

protected void begin() {
    getSession().beginTransaction();
}

protected void commit() {
    getSession().getTransaction().commit();

}


protected void rollback() {
    try {
        getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        getSession().close();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    BaseDAO.session.set(null);
}


public  void close() {
    getSession().close();
    BaseDAO.session.set(null);
}
   }
```

Then the class that extends it

```
     package DAO;

   import java.util.Iterator;

   import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
   import org.hibernate.Query;

   import pojo.Address;
   import pojo.Clinic;
   import pojo.Patient;

    public class PatientDAO extends BaseDAO {


  public PatientDAO(){

  } 

    It takes more 4 seconds to add just 100 elements so roughly bout 8 mins to 
    add    10K elements. Is there some thing erong with my code. i.e the 
    SAVE() method Below.And ya i tried removing the additional update that i am doing 
    it did not make much difference. 
    I have beeen asked to bring the time for 10K to <1 min..!! :( please help 

     public void create(Patient p) throws ApplicationException {
    try {
         begin();
         getSession().save(p);
         Query query = getSession().createQuery
          ("update Address  patientid=? where id=?");

         query.setParameter(0,p.getId());
         query.setParameter(1, p.getAddress().getId());
         query.executeUpdate();
         commit();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        rollback();
        throw new ApplicationException(e.getCause().getMessage());
    } 
 }
```

Hibernate cfg.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">self</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 /rajtest1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">rajtest1</property>

   <property  name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
      <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

    <!--  property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property-->
     <!--property  
     name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property-->
       <property name="show_sql">false</property>
       <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" >update</property>
     <mapping resource ="Clinic.hbm.xml"/>
               <mapping resource="Doctor.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="Patient.hbm.xml"/>
       <mapping resource="Address.hbm.xml"/>
      </session-factory>
       </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Let me paraphrase your question: *I have some code, and it's slow. Why?* Could you answer such a question?

Comment: I am sorry it should have been in more detail i know . goes like the following code

Comment: Sorry @JB Nizet. . Now i ve put the code .Thanks fr making me aware

Answer (score 1):

First:

You do a commit for every insert. That is inefficient. It is definitively more efficient to do one commit for many inserts.

Second:

Why do you do an update on the address after creating the patient? Probably you've created the address just before. It is more efficient to define the address as a member of the patient object (for example with a many-to-one or one-to-one relation) and insert both together with a single save (use cascade) or insert the address after the patient. In this cases hibernate manages setting the patientid in address.

third:

Trace your SQL statements with

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

in the hibernate configuration file and look if there are superfluous SQL statements,

Fourth:

Try the inserts directly in the SQL command line. Perhaps your database isn't faster.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot.! Solved the problem don't know why but when i started closing the session after commit. the time reduced.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to save 10000 records you should not be doing them one at a time.  Create a proc to do a set-based insert or update instead of using n_Hibernate.